# Int iterable error

Tags: python

Hi I have the below code and got this error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, I guess its related to the variable c

```
def dayInWeek(self):
    m = self._month, y = self._year, c = 0 ; # m - the month , _day - the day , c - the decade, y - the last 2 digit in the year
    if self._month == 1 or self._month == 2:
        m = self._month + 12
        y = self._year - 1
    c = m / 100
    y = y % 100
    return (self._day + (26 * (m +1)) / 10 + y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c) % 7
```

Comment: There is no need for guessing. Include a _complete_ error message. It will tell you (and us) where exactly is the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare multiple variables on the same line like you're doing. Change

```
m = self._month, y = self._year, c = 0
```

To

```
m = self._month
y = self._year
c = 0
```

Declaring multiple variables on the same line is generally considered bad practice anyways in most cases.

The error here is because using commas on the left hand side of an assignment is interpreted as trying to deconstruct what's on the right into a tuple. 0 can't be deconstructed since it's not an iterable; thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

Python does support multiple variable assignments, but not the way you are doing it (which is how it would work in C).

Instead of

```
m = self._month, y = self._year, c = 0
```

Just do

```
m, y, c = self._month, self._year, 0
```

This form of assignment is called [tuple assignment](http://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/).

Note that you don't need to declare `c` here either, just define it where you need it:

```
def dayInWeek(self):
    d, m, y = self._day, self._month, self._year
    if m in (1, 2):
        m += 12
        y -= 1
    c = m / 100
    y %= 100
    return (d + (26 * (m +1)) / 10 + y + y / 4 + c / 4 - 2 * c) % 7
```

Also, leave the trailing `;` out, they are not necessary in Python.

Comment: I’d recommend against doing this, as it makes the code harder to read. Tuple assignment is better for cases where the variables are all very closely related or from a function return. In my opinion, at least.

Comment: @Scovetta I agree that it can do that, but here all parts are actually related (especially when not including the decade as I did in the later code). And assigning related parts with tuple assignments is very readable IMO.